# Mute/Unmute Application Sounds

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

How do I mute/unmute sounds in my application without touching the master volume control of my computer when the the code I'm using is:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.audio_here, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `waveOutSetVolume` and `waveOutGetVolume` functions in winmm.dll

```
Private Declare Function waveOutSetVolume Lib "winmm.dll" (ByVal uDeviceID As Integer, ByVal dwVolume As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function waveOutGetVolume Lib "winmm.dll" (ByVal uDeviceID As Integer, ByRef lpdwVolume As Integer) As Integer
```

[waveOutSetVolume Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[waveOutGetVolume Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Depending on the OS version of your target machines, you may need to look into using the newer `MMDevice` and `EndpointVolume` APIs.

[EndpointVolume Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How do I get the uDeviceID?

Comment: We've always been able to get away with specifying 0 for the uDeviceID.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I spend 10+ hours trying different options and translating C++ and C# codes into VB.net and finaly this one seems to work at least for me. Try it your self

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1

<DllImport("winmm.dll")>
Public Shared Function waveOutSetVolume(ByVal h As IntPtr, ByVal dwVolume As UInteger) As Integer
End Function


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Show()

    Dim keyValue As String  'disable web click sound
    keyValue = "%SystemRoot%\Media\"
    If Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major = 5 AndAlso Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor > 0 Then
        keyValue += "Windows XP Start.wav"
    ElseIf Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major = 6 Then
        keyValue += "Windows Navigation Start.wav"
    Else
        Return
    End If
    Dim key As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\Navigating\.Current", True)
    key.SetValue(Nothing, "", RegistryValueKind.ExpandString)

    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/some_video")
    waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, 0)


End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);

//mute application
private void mute(){
{
    int NewVolume = 0; //set 0 to unmute
    uint NewVolumeAllChannels = (((uint)NewVolume & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint)NewVolume << 16));
    waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, NewVolumeAllChannels);
}

//unmute application
private void unmute(){
{
    int NewVolume = 65535; //set 65535 to unmute
    uint NewVolumeAllChannels = (((uint)NewVolume & 0x0000ffff) | ((uint)NewVolume << 16));
    waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, NewVolumeAllChannels);
}
```

Comment: How to specify application to mute/unmute with this code?