# How to disable 'sound muting' option through VB.NET?

Tags: security, vb.net

I'm developing a security based VB.NET project where an alarm is sounded when the user attempts wrong passwords. But as of now, simply muting the speakers through the Sound Control option has been an obstacle for my project.
Assuming that speakers are not mutable by manual methods, is there a way to prevent 'volume reduction' or other similar things using VB.NET? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2013.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mute/Unmute Application Sounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745779/mute-unmute-application-sounds)

Comment: @TheBlueDog This is not about disabling Application sounds. I need to prevent the user from reducing the volume, not just Sounds.

Comment: And what do you suppose your 'alarm' is if it's not an application sound? Use the APIs in the linked question to unmute and wind the volume up before you trigger your sound.

Comment: The 'Alarm' referred here is just an .mp3 file being played.

Comment: Which is an application sound ...

Comment: I mean to control the master volume. Not just the sound by my application.

Comment: Maybe you should edit you question to be more explicit then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider running the app under a user with different Local Policy defined than the end user. The app is allowed to adjust volume, the user isn't.